# wait file to create before send mail

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Im having some problems with a function with nodemailer, i need to create a pdf from body req, then attach it to a mail and send it, the problem here is i dont know how to wait to the file to finish saving before send the mail, and im having errors because the mails goes before the system can create the file or even attach the pdf file...

the idea will be: send post req -> get the req.body -> create pdf -> create mail options (nodemailer) -> send the mail.

but the code now is going like: send post req -> get the req.body -> create pdf -> create mail options (nodemailer) -> send the mail -> system
still making the pdf -> error

my current code is:

```html
 app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
        if (req.body.email == "" || req.body.subject == "") {
            res.send("Error: Email & Subject should not blank");
            return false;
        }

        // Sending Emails with SMTP, Configuring SMTP settings

        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "mail.vyg.cl", // hostname
            secureConnection: true, // use SSL
            port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
            auth: {
                user: 'crm@vyg.cl',
                pass: '******'
            }
        });
        const pdfArchive = './server/' + req.body.subject + '.pdf';


        if (fs.existsSync(pdfArchive)) {
            fs.unlinkSync(pdfArchive);
        }
        pdf.create(req.body.description).toFile('./server/' + req.body.subject + '.pdf', function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(res)

            }
        });

        const mailOptions = {
            from: req.body.from, // sender address
            to: req.body.to, // list of receivers
            cc: req.body.cc,
            subject: req.body.subject, // Subject line
            //text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
            // html: req.body.description, // html body,
            attachments: [{ // file on disk as an attachment
                filename: req.body.subject + '.pdf',
                path: './server/' + req.body.subject + '.pdf' // stream this file
            }]
        }
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
            if (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ message: "Email could not sent due to error: " + error });
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({ message: "Email has been sent successfully" });
            }
        });
        if (fs.existsSync(pdfArchive)) {
            fs.unlinkSync(pdfArchive);
        }
    });
```

i tryed to send the mail in the conditional when the pdf was created but i dont get the smtpTransport response....

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
app.post('/send', async function(req, res) {
        if (req.body.email == "" || req.body.subject == "") {
            res.send("Error: Email & Subject should not blank");
            return false;
        }

        // Sending Emails with SMTP, Configuring SMTP settings

        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "mail.vyg.cl", // hostname
            secureConnection: true, // use SSL
            port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
            auth: {
                user: 'crm@vyg.cl',
                pass: '*******'
            }
        });
  
        const mailOptions = {
            from: req.body.from, // sender address
            to: req.body.to, // list of receivers
            cc: req.body.cc,
            subject: req.body.subject, // Subject line
            //text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
            // html: req.body.description, // html body,
            attachments: [{ // file on disk as an attachment
                filename: req.body.subject + '.pdf',
                path: './server/' + req.body.subject + '.pdf' // stream this file
            }]
        }
  
        const pdfArchive = './server/' + req.body.subject + '.pdf';


        if (fs.existsSync(pdfArchive)) {
            await fs.unlinkSync(pdfArchive);// Add wait here
        }
        try{
   
   var result = await pdf.create(req.body.description).toFile('./server/' + req.body.subject + '.pdf') // capture result if you need to
   try{
   await smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions) // wrap this in a try catch if you want to capture email sending specific erorrs else outer try catch will work 
   res.status(200).json({ message: "Email has been sent successfully" });
   
   }
   catch(error)
   {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Email could not sent due to error: " + error });
   }
  }
  catch(error)
  {
   console.log(err);
   res.send(error)
  }
    });
```